Parallel lines intersecting far away
An Electrical Engineer here. Had this thought observation while I was sitting on my porch and looking at some landmarks a little far away from my house. I would appreciate it if answers were given back in EE friendly format; I am not a math major lol.

In the pic:
y = 1 and y = 3 are obviously parallel.
Angle BAG = 90.00 deg
Angle CAG = 33.69 deg
( Found this angle by making a imaginary right triangle, by drawing an imaginary vertical line from point C to y=1)
Angle DAG = 18.43 deg
( Found this angle by making a imaginary right triangle, by drawing an imaginary vertical line from point D to y=1)
Angle EAG = 15.94 deg
( Found this angle by making a imaginary right triangle, by drawing an imaginary vertical line from point E to y=1)
Angle FAG = 12.52 deg
( Found this angle by making a imaginary right triangle, by drawing an imaginary vertical line from point F to y=1)
So, it seems to me that, as we choose a point on y = 3 that is located farther to the right, the angle between that particular point and A (1,1) and G (9,1) keeps decreasing and eventually goes towards zero.
In other words, as the 'x' coordinate of an ordered pair located on y = 3 goes more positive, the angle between that particular ordered pair and A (1,1) and G (9,1) decreases.
In other words, Angle SAG, where point 'S' has its x-coordinate as infinity,  will be zero using the formula theta = tan^-1( rise / run ).
In other words, if we build a imaginary right angled triangle SAQ ,the Angle SAQ will be zero.
If Angle SAQ becomes zero somewhere far far far away on the far right side of the graph paper;  that would mean:

Point S ( Infinity, 3) is  ending up touching the line y = 1 somewhere far far to the right.
If Point S ( Infinity, 3 ) ends up touching y = 1 somewhere on the far right, then that would mean that y = 3 is also 'running' into y = 1 and thereby intersecting y = 1.

This is wierd, cause y= 3 and y =1, which are parallel should never intersect.
Let us forget about the points being located at infinity and assume that they are at a x-coordinate value of 10,000. That still makes that angle pretty close to zero. What would that mean for the parallelism of both lines?
How will the problem change if the x-coordinate was not infinity but was a rather huge number like 10,000?
My question, as an EE who tries to exploit extreme instances in physics, math etc for human good, is if can someone tell me if y = 1 and y = 3 do indeed "bend" towards each other or "move closer" in any way in real life.
I am assuming that some of u will say that y = 1 and y = 3 will never intersect.
I would have no problem with that, but in that case can u guys atleast tell me, this:
If they dont intersect, then does it mean that the distance between them is constant always, or do they never intersect as in, they come pretty close to a hairbreadth of touching each other/intersecting but just never ever intersect or touch?
( My question is different from the suggested duplicate because that other question talks about eye vision perception etc.
The other question is using vision perception to make its point while I am using hard math to make my point )

The short answer to your conundrum is that there is no point (infinity, 3) that would end up on both these parallel lines. They just plain do not intersect, not "on paper" nor anywhere else.
For a longer answer, you could learn about projective geometry, at wikipedia or many other links

@EthanBolker How will the problem change if the x-coordinate of points S and Q was not infinity but was a rather huge number like 10,000? ( I feel 10,000 is pretty fair of a number compared to infinity ).That would make the angle pretty close to zero. In that case, would it mean that atleast one of the parallel lines was 'creeping' towards the other?

@peterwhy If the x-coordinate of points S and Q was 10,000, that would make the angle pretty close to zero. In that case, would it mean that atleast one of the parallel lines was 'creeping' towards the other? i am pretty sure we could have a paper 10,000 units long, in case we can't have an infinite size paper :).

Re: your comment where "the x-coordinate of points S and Q was 10,000". The angle between $S$ and $Q$, as viewed from $x=1$, is pretty close to zero but not zero. The actual distance $SQ$ is still $2$.

@peterwhy So which answer is the real answer? Is the distance still 2 or is the angle almost 0? I agree that using a tape measure will show us that the distance between S and Q is still 2 ( i hope! ) , but what does the angle being almost close to zero mean in real life?

Why not both? The distance $SQ$ is still $2$; depending on your tolerance of "almost 0", anyway the angle $\angle SAQ = \tan^{-1} \frac{2}{9999} \approx 0.011^\circ$.

Close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades.  The angle is $\arctan \frac 3{y}$.  If $y = 100,000$ then the angel is $\arctan 0.000003$ which, sure, it's "close" to $0$.  But it isn't $0$.  If you want to say it is close enough to $0$ within a margin of error, then in essence the problem is not solvable within the range of marginal error.  There really isn't anything more to say.

@fleablood If the angle is arctan 0.000003, why wouldn't it mean that one of the lines is moving towards the other? Is there some sort of binary state that the lines are in, where either they are intersecting fully or not intersecting at all without an 'inbetween' state, which the decreasing angle values seem to imply?

$\arctan \frac 2{10000}$ is not really any proportionally "closer" to $0$ then $\frac 2{10000}$ is.  If you can accept that at $10,000$ units the angle is essentially $0$ then you can just as accurately claim at $10,000$ units $2$ units is essentially $0$.  This really isn't anything out of the ordinary.

"If the angle is arctan 0.000003, why wouldn't it mean that one of the lines is moving towards the other?" Of course not.  "Is there some sort of binary state that the lines are in, where either they are intersecting fully or not intersecting at all without an 'inbetween' state" Of course not.  "which the decreasing angle values seem to imply?" Decreasing angles do not imply anything of the sort.  Decreasing, but not zero, angles only imply decreasing angles.  Any value that isn't $0$, no matter how small, isn't $0$.

If you are a human being $6$ feet is $100%$ of your height.  If you are a cat it is $1000%$ of your height.  If you are a skyscraper is it $0.01%$ of your height and if you are the diameter of the planet it is insignificant.  But it is still $6$ feet.  That is exactly the same thing as what you are asking about. No different at all. Have you heard the puzzle that if 8 feet were added to a snug steel band around the equator, and it was evened out, it would raise by a little over 2 feet. It's the same issue.

Although the angle approaches zero, it never actually becomes zero because $y=3$ and $y=1$ are separate lines that never touch, and are always parallel to each other.
